# convert a string cointaing a base 10 number to an integer value

Tags: c, string

I am fairly new to programming and I am trying to convert a string containing a base 10 number to an integer value following this pseudo algorithm in c.

```
start with n = 0
read a character from the string and call it c 
if the value of c is between '0' and '9' (48 and 57):
   n = n * 10 +(c-'0')
   read the next character from the string and repeat
else return n
```

here is the rough basics of what i wrote down however I am not clear on how to read a character from the string. i guess im asking if i understand the pseudocode correctly.

```
stoi(char *string){
  int n = 0;
  int i;
  char c;
  for (i = 0;i < n ; i++){
      if (c[i] <= '9' && c[i] >= '0'){
          n = n *10 +(c - '0')}
      else{
           return n
           }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've declared `c` as a `char`, which means it represents one single character, which means that you can't use it as `c[i]`, because a single character has nothing that can be indexed. You missed the part that says *read a character from the string and call it c* and *read the next character from the string and repeat*.

Comment: You've got two main mistakes.  You're mixing up several of your variables. (1) The input string you're processing is `string`.  So you want to be working with `string[i]`, not `c[i]`.  (I don't think you need that variable `c` at all.) (2) `n` is the number you're constructing.  It starts out as `0`, which is correct.  But that means `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` is wrong, because you want to loop over all the characters in the string.  But since `n` starts out as 0, the loop will never run.  You probably want the loop to run over all the characters in `string`, that is, `strlen(string)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, you just need to traverse the string to get the value of each digit.

Basically you have two ways to do it.

Using array notation:

```
int stoi(const char *str)
{
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        char c = str[i];

        if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
        {
            n = n * 10 + (c - '0');
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

or using pointer arithmetic:

```
int stoi(const char *str)
{
    int n = 0;

    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        char c = *str;

        if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
        {
            n = n * 10 + (c - '0');
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Note that in both cases we iterate until the null character `'\0'` (which is the one that marks the end of the string) is found.

Also, prefer `const char *string` over `char *string` when the function doesn't need to modify the string (like in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on starting your C journey!

One of the most important aspects of strings in C is that, technically, there are none. A `string` is not a primitive type like in Java. You CAN'T do:

```
String myString = "Hello";
```

In C, each `string` is just an array of multiple characters. That means the word `Hello` is just the array of `[H,e,l,l,o,\0]`. Here, the `\0` indicates the end of the word. This means you can easily access any character in a string by using indexes (like in a normal array):

```
char *myString = "Hello";
printf("%c", myString[0]); //Here %c indicates to print a character
```

This will then print `H`, since `H` is the first character in the string. I hope you can see how you can access the any character in the string.